# What are the implications of the "public port" setting?

Tags: marklogic

One of the settings for a MarkLogic app server is "**public port**" (`true`/`false`).

The setting description in the Admin UI says:

> Whether the port is accessible from the public internet.

The help tab's description is:

> specifies whether this port can be accessed by anyone on the internet.

I don't see any reference to this setting in the documentation.

What are the implications of this setting?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is sparse, but I believe this was added in order to facilitate Data Hub Service and more fine grained security controls and management.

For a local install I don't think it has any impact.